# In MVP Design Pattern for android, where we put Business login in?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, kotlin, android-mvp

I had some confuse where should I put business login in between Model and Presenter. Some tutorials say that model hold business login and some say that model is only POJO.

Answer (score 1):

Business logic should be in `Model`. Application logic should be in `Presenter`

Example:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity implements MyView {
    private MyPresenter mPresenter;

    @Override public onLoginResponse(LoginResultEntity entity) {
        // Handle login result
    }

    // Some where 
    mPresenter = new MyPresenter();
    mPresenter.attachView(this);
    mPresenter.login(loginResquestEntity);
}

public class MyPresenter extends BasePresenter<MyView>{
    public void login(LoginResquestEntity loginResquestEntity) {
        // Validate info ...
        ApiManager.getInstance().login(loginResquestEntity, new Callback() {
            @Override public onSuccess(LoginResultEntity entity) {
                mMvpView.onLoginResponse(entity)
            }

            @Override public onError(Throwable throwable) {
                mMvpView.onLoginResponse(null)
            }
        });
    }
}

interface MyView extends MvpView {
    void onLoginResponse(LoginResultEntity entity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where to put business logic is confusing. It should be part of model. I created a additional layer over model calling it service that performs operations on model and it has logic to deal with model. So if in future I change from SQLite to Room DB Or GreenDao ORM  just query regarding that needs to be changed and my business logic will be intact. There are application logic that is different from business logic that should be in presenter.

Answer (score 0):

In **MVP** design pattern Model is not our pojo class , sometimes we call Model as repository also .

**M-MODEL(REPOSITORY)**

**V-VIEW**

**P-PRESENTER**

In MODEL(REPOSITORY) :- its handle Api,database operations etc

So from now lets call **MODEL** as **Repository** .